# Binding parameters to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a result from a mysql database with PHP.

I am using a query like this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE  images.name LIKE ?  OR  images.title LIKE ?
```

And this is how I bind the parameters to the query:

```
$f_for = "%". $filter_for ."%";
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $f_for, $f_for);
```

---

If I replace the questionmarks `?` with a made up search string, so the query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE  images.name LIKE '%searchForThis%'  OR  images.title LIKE '%searchForThis%'
```

and execute it directly (not PHP, but phpMyAdmin or directly via terminal), I get a correct/positive result (ie I am getting rows back, where the search string matches a value in one of the two columns).

---

Using the parameterized query I do not get any errors, but just an empty result (ie zero rows). I tried different string formats, but it seems like none of these work either.

```
$f_for = "'%". $filter_for ."%'";
$f_for = "%{$filter_for}%";
```

How do I correctly bind the parameters? Am I doing it completely wrong or could it be another problem?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I did, but I could not find any possible mistakes ...

Comment: Since `bind_param` binds the parameters by reference, it *might* be choking on the fact that you're passing the same variable in twice... if you're using `pdo` you could try `bind_value()` instead or simply create two variables holding identical values: e.g. `$f_for1` and `$f_for2`

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: @CD001 `bind_value()` is for getting data out of a result set not setting parameter values

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... I was thinking of `PDOStatement::bindValue()` ... if they were using PDO (which they're not - ummm, yeah) ... are you thinking of `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` - looks like `mysqi_stmt::bind_value()` doesn't actually exist :)

Comment: One way to track it is to turn on general_log in mysql when running the query. It should show you exactly what the query is, and might help when trying to figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: @CD001 hehhhehehe I heard th penny drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am about to hit my head against a wall and I am truly sorry everyone...

Looking at the general logs, as suggested by aynber I found `LIMIT 0, 0` at the end of my query, so it would always return zero rows.

I am ashamed that I asked this question.

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote this just for the facepalm moment ... we've all been there! :D

Comment: I've fixed so many issues just by logging queries! You start focusing on one part of the problem that you become blind to the rest of it.

Comment: So what did you do to actually fix the issue?

Comment: Removing `LIMIT 0, 0` from the end of the query solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can do it, and it involves a lot less fiddling about with `$filter_for`

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM images
        WHERE  images.name LIKE ? OR  images.title LIKE ?"

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$param = "%$filter_for%";

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $param, $param);
```

Comment: uh, I am getting a fatal error doing it like that: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`

Comment: You are doing a prepare in the middle of that I assume?

Comment: Is that any better?? Sorry my mistake, it wont like passing a non variable for some reason

Comment: @user5888833 I just ran through this on my dev box... been a while since I used `mysqli` rather than `pdo` ... to get a recordset with mysqli you either need to use `get_result()` (with mysqlnd) or you can `$stmt->bind_result()` and then do a `$stmt->fetch()` loop : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score -3):

Please use concatenation like this

```
$f_for = "'%".$filter_for."%'";
```

Comment: You dont need the leading and trailing single quotes

Comment: bind_param adds the quotes as needed.