# Trying to update database table content value

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmailer

I'm trying to update the value of "verified" in my database table contents. The "verified" content is set to "false" I'm using PHPMailer to send a email verification link, once the user clicks the button/link I want to change the verified table from "false" to "true". Here is the code I'm using, the email sends just fine but when the link is clicked it doesn't update the table. (I removed sensitive information)

```
<?php


require 'controllers/authController.php';

require_once 'db/config.php';

$name = $_SESSION['username'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];



use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try{
// Server Settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->Port = ;

// Recipients
$mail->setFrom('', '');
$mail->addAddress($email);

$body = '<!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
         <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
         </head>
         <body>
         <form method="post">
         <div class="wrapper">
          Hi, &nbsp;' . $name . '! <p>Please click the link below to verify your account.</p><br>
         <button class = btn btn-primary verifylink><a href="localhost/gitscripts/home.php">Verify Email</a></button>
         </form>';

if(isset($_GET['verifylink'])){
    $verified = true;

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET verified=[true]";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('b', $verified);
}



// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Verify Your Email';
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e){
echo 'Message could not send';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Here is the specific line of code that I used to try and pull this off...

```
if(isset($_GET['verifylink'])){
    $verified = true;

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET verified=[true]";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('b', $verified);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this `"UPDATE users SET verified=true";`? You are changing **ALL** users

Answer (score 2):

If `verified` is of either `bit` or `boolean` type, then use the following:

```
UPDATE users SET verified = 1 -- Alternatively, set to 0 for false
```

If you really don't want to run a hard-coded query, you need to use the `?` operator inside your query, which will be replaced with the value you supply in  `$stmt->bind_param('b', $verified)`:

```
UPDATE users SET verified = ?
```

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227715/binding-parameters-to-mysql-query) to see the complete integration

Comment: if(isset($_GET['verifylink'])){
        $verified = true;
        
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET verified=?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('b', $verified);
    }                                                                                                                   I just tried this, and it still doesn't update the database value.